ADF dataflow contain file names in single file sink
I am comparing the title in movies.csv, which matches the title element in the json files, and then appending the filename to list.txt in the sink. Assume "Big Hero" and "Moana" are match in file1.json and file5.json. However, ADF returns both entire file1.json and file5.json to the sink.
I only want to see the filename "file1.json" and "file5.json" in list.txt.
title.csv:

The Lion King
Big Hero
Moana

the final result in list.txt (sink):

file1.json

file5.json
ADF dataflow setup:
source option>column to store file name>list
derivedColumn1>Columns>Title and expression lower(trim(record.metadata.Title))
lookup1>primary stream> derivedColumn1
lookup1>lookup stream> sourceCSV
filter1>filter on> isNull(sourceCSV@title) == false()
sink>column data> list




You have enough credit to know this is a poor question. Please post coherent questions...I do not want to post a guide on how to ask questions for a user with over 1k credits


I only want to see the filename "file1.json" and "file5.json" in list.txt.

After getting the required rows, you can use select transformation to get only the required filename column.
Before the lookup, ensure the rows in your source csv file are changed to lower case using a derived column transformation.

Now, after using filter transformation, use select transformation with Rule-based mapping as shown below.
name=='filename'


Now, add your text file as sink in the dataflow and run the dataflow from the pipeline.
It will generate the target text file as expected.


Thank you so much. It works
